# SQL: Join Three Tables - Combined Inner / Left Outer Join?

Tags: sql

having a bit of trouble visualizing how a join should look for a particular result set I'm trying to achieve.

I have three tables: Projects, Recommendations, Services. Recommendations is just a join table between Projects and Services, i.e. a project can have zero or more recommended services; to capture that relationship, the Recommendations table has a project_id and service_id for each recommendation record.

So, relevant fields:

```
Projects.id | Recommendations.project_id | Recommendations.service_id | Services.id
```

I'm trying to pull a list of all projects for which there is NO recommendation for a specific service. I have the following, which pulls all projects for which there are no recommendations at all, and that is:

```
SELECT * from projects P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Recommendations R ON P.id = R.project_id 
WHERE R.project_id IS NULL
```

I know I need to join on the Services table as well, but I'm not sure how I should structure it. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: There is no relationship between `Projects` and `Services` other than through the `Recommendations` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT P.* from projects P
LEFT JOIN Recommendations R 
    ON P.id = R.project_id 
LEFT JOIN  Services S 
    ON S.Service_id = R.service_id and s.ID = 10
WHERE s.service_id is null
```

This should find those records that do not have service id is 10. Note I took out where 
clause R.project_id IS NULL. You could also use the subquery approach (which is likely to be faster, but test both.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM recommendations R
                    JOIN  Services S 
                        ON S.Service_id = R.service_id 
                    WHERE project_id=projects.id and s.ID = 10)
```

Of course in real life you would not want to use select * ever. Please put the actual fields you want in the select portion.

Comment: +1: But, you don't even need to join to the `Services` table. Just `...LEFT JOIN Recommendations R ON P.id = R.project_id AND R.service_id = 10 WHERE R.service_id IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks - this looks closer to what I need. there is no S.service_id though; the key for each table is simply 'id'. I'll tinker with this. I only did select * for purposes of the question because it was shorter to type - I don't actually pull back everythign in my app.

Comment: Joe - wouldn't that always pull back zero rows? It looks like you're joining where R.service_id = 10 and R.service_id IS NULL.

Comment: Not if the  R.service_id = 10  is part of the join and the R.service_id IS NULL is inthe where clause.

Answer (score 2):

One option is the subquery approach, without any join:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM recommendations WHERE project_id=projects.id AND recommendations.service_id=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This just returns the same result as the query in my post, which is to say it shows me all projects for which there are zero recommendations for any service. What I am trying to do is get a list of projects for which there are zero recommendations for one SPECIFIC service, i.e. there may be other recommendations for that project.

Comment: Sorry for not reading too quickly. @HLGEM's solution below seems pretty good, and a join on the services table indeed seems superfluous - so basically I'm adding "AND recommendations.service_id=10" to my subquery suggestion above.