# MySQL: Many to Many Join Where Not Exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm posting this question again because I think I may have worded it poorly last time, and the solution I thought was working, isn't.

I have 3 tables: Projects, Services, and Recommendations. Recommendations provides the many-to-many relationship between Projects and Services, i.e. each row in Recommendations has a project_id and a service_id.

Let's say there are 1000 projects, and 5 services. I would expect no greater than 5000 records in my Recommendations table, but almost certainly fewer (i.e. some projects have no service recommendations). So, for project #1, if all 5 services have been recommended, I would see 5 rows in the Recommendations table like:

```
project_id   service_id
1            1
1            2
1            3
1            4
1            5
```

What I am trying to do is build a query that shows me which projects do NOT have all 5 services recommended, and which those are. So let's say project #1 only had the first 3 services recommended; the output of my query showing which ones are missing might look like:

```
project_id   service_id
1            4
1            5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Prev question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169625/sql-join-three-tables-combined-inner-left-outer-join

Comment: If you reference a prior question older than an hour or so, it's nice to include a link, especially when you say the prior answer didn't work :)

Comment: Indeed, sorry! Noted for future reference :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select P.project_id, S.service_id
From Projects As P
    Cross Join Services As S
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From Recommendations As R1
                    Where R1.project_id = P.project_id
                        And R1.service_id = S.service_id
                    )
```

Another variant which should work in MySQL

```
Select P.project_id, S.service_id
From Projects As P
    Cross Join Services As S
Where (P.project_id, S.service_id) Not In   (
                                            Select R1.project_Id, R1.service_id
                                            From Recommendations As R1
                                            )
```

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - Actually, from what I have read it is Inner Join that can behave like a Cross Join if you do not use an On clause or Where clause that joins the keys.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - From the docs, basically you can use a Cross Join to behave like an Inner Join if you include an On clause or Where clause. That's fine. Either way, I want the Cartesian product which I'll get without an On or Where.

Comment: @Thomas: I stand (OK, I'm actually sitting) corrected. I'll drop the comment and +1.

Comment: @Thomas, I fixed some typos in your second query and it works now.

Comment: Thanks for the input! So far, this has hung my db server for a few minutes - it has grabbed 100% CPU for about 4 minutes, and running. Not sure if I should expect that with a cross join?

Comment: @David - Depending on equipment, I wouldn't expect it to take long with only 5000 combinations on most database systems. Which variant of my answer are you using?

Comment: I used the 2nd version, which ultimately worked - as did Ike's below. I actually have more than 1000 projects; I was just using that for the sake of simplicity in this problem. My result returned 8388 rows after about 4 minutes :) It's not a beefy machine so I don't expect much. Thanks for the help +1 and correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE now that I read the question correctly. I'll still use an outer join, but no sub-query this time:

```
SELECT p.project_id,s.service_id
FROM projects p
cross join services s
LEFT OUTER JOIN recommendations r on r.project_id = p.project_id and r.service_id = s.service_id
WHERE r.project_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Ike! Yours worked as well, but I gave it to Thomas simply because I started using his solution first. +1

Comment: No problem. They will return the exact same data, but I recommend that you compare the performance of the two queries. I expect mine to be at least 40% faster.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simplistic option is this:

```
select project_id, count(*)
from recommendations
group by project_id
having count(distinct service_id) < (select count(*) from services)
```